# How to properly install a NumPy ufunc?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, numpy-ufunc

I am trying to install an example ufunc from the [SciPy Docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/c-info.ufunc-tutorial.html) but when I run `python setup.py build` or `python setup.py install` I get a few warnings about a deprecated NumPy API.

When I run `python setup.py install` this is the output:

```
$ python setup.py install
running install
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompileroptions
running build_src
build_src
building extension "npufunc_directory.npufunc" sources
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
running build_ext
customize UnixCCompiler
customize UnixCCompiler using build_ext
building 'npufunc_directory.npufunc' extension
compiling C sources
C compiler: gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python/python-2.7.8-1.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/python-2.7.8-1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python/python-2.7.8-1.x86_64/src/Python-2.7.8=/usr/src/debug/python-2.7.8-1 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes
creating build
creating build/temp.cygwin-1.7.32-x86_64-2.7
compile options: '-I/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c'
gcc: single_type_logit.c
In file included from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1728:0,
             from single_type_logit.c:3:
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_deprecated_api.h:11:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp] #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION"
creating build/lib.cygwin-1.7.32-x86_64-2.7
creating build/lib.cygwin-1.7.32-x86_64-2.7/npufunc_directory
gcc -shared -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base -L. build/temp.cygwin-1.7.32-x86_64-2.7/single_type_logit.o -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config -L/usr/lib -lpython2.7 -o build/lib.cygwin-1.7.32-x86_64-2.7/npufunc_directory/npufunc.dll
running scons
running install_lib
copying build/lib.cygwin-1.7.32-x86_64-2.7/npufunc_directory/npufunc.dll -> /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/npufunc_directory
running install_egg_info
Removing /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/npufunc_directory-0.0.0-py2.7.egg-info
Writing /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/npufunc_directory-0.0.0-py2.7.egg-info
running install_clib
customize UnixCCompiler
```

running `python setup.py build` produces:

```
$ python setup.py build
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building extension "npufunc_directory.npufunc" sources
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
running build_ext
customize UnixCCompiler
customize UnixCCompiler using build_ext
running scons
```

If I try to import the module I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import npufunc
ImportError: No module named npufunc
```

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: Can you check `from npufunc_directory import npufunc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/modules.html#packages) "The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages". The setup.py in the Numpy documentation does not create this file, so Python does not import anything as it ignores this directory.

Solution: just add an empty `__init__.py` file in the  `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/npufunc_directory` directory, for example with `sudo touch __init__.py` Then try:

```
>>> from npufunc_directory import npufunc
>>> npufunc.logit(.5)
0.0
```

Alternatively, add `import npufunc` to the `__init__.py` and then you can do:

```
>>> import npufunc_directory
>>> npufunc_directory.npufunc.logit(0.5)
0.0
```